# How to integrate android oflline map without internet

Tags: android-studio

how to integrate an offline map? am trying this?

private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

```
    // Downloading data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        // For storing data from web service
        String data = "";

        try {
            // Fetching the data from web service
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            Log.d("DownloadTask", "DownloadTask : " + data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
    // doInBackground()
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

        // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
        parserTask.execute(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use mapbox, openstreetMap or osmdroid!
https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid
https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/offline/
https://www.openstreetmap.org/